# Notifying golongpoll.SubscriptionManager of an event from kafka-go

Tags: go, apache-kafka, long-polling

I was writing a POC on long-polling using go.
I see the general package to be used is https://github.com/jcuga/golongpoll .
But assuming that I would want to publish an event to the golongpoll.SubscriptionManager from a general context, especially when there is a possibility that the long poll API request is being served by one machine, while the Kafka event for that particular consumer group is consumed by another instance in the cluster.

The examples given in the documentation did not talk of such a scenario at all, even though this seems like a common scenario. One way I can think of is have a distributed cache like Redis in between and have all the services poll this for a change? But that sounds a bit dumb to me.

Comment: Also of note, what if there are multiple parallel requests from the same client.